# Url routing issue in asp.net mvc 

Tags: asp.net-mvc, indexing, url-routing, action

I am doing a `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Clients");` from my home controller.... It is fine but my url looks like `http://localhost:1115/Clients/Index`... How to remove index from url in asp.net mvc? Any suggestion....

My routes,

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Registrations",                                             
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           
            new { controller = "Registration", action = "Create", id = "" }    
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Clients",                                              
            "Clients/{action}/{id}",                           
            new { controller = "Clients", action = "Index", id = "" }  
        );
    }
```

But still it doesn't seem to remove `index` from my url...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your default action to `Index` or create an new route like

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Clients",                                             
            "Clients/{action}/{id}",                           
            new { controller = "Clients", action = "Index", id = "" }    
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by just pushing my default route to the bottom as stated in one of the answers for [asp.net-mvc default route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973205/asp-net-mvc-default-route)