# How to add multiple routes to MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, routes

To define your own URL routes in ASP.NET MVC4, I believe you modify Global.asax.cs so it looks something like...

```
using System.Web.Mvc; 
using System.Web.Routing; 
namespace MvcApplication1 { 
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication { 
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) { 
            routes.MapRoute( .....
```

But what I cant find anywhere, is how you add multiple routes - e.g. do you just call `routes.MapRoute(....)` again?

Also, does this overwrite the hidden default routing definitions? If I want to keep it do I need to define it also?

Comment: to add routes check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201(v=vs.100).aspx#adding_routes_to_an_mvc_application

Comment: You tagged this as [tag:asp.net-mvc-4] so I'd recommend using the MVC4 way and wire up your routes in the `/App_Start/RouteConfig.cs` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add multiple routes, kindly check this [adding_routes_to_an_mvc_application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#adding_routes_to_an_mvc_application). As you said just make call `routes.MapRoute(....)` again.

The one thing to put into consideration MVC Routing respect ordering route. Your last route must be generic as possible, and your previous route must be specific as possible.(check this out [ASP.NET MVC Default route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973205/asp-net-mvc-default-route#answer-1036237))

> does this overwrite the hidden default routing definitions?

I don't think so, but your reoutes sure 'll be checked first before the default MVC routes.(check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252925/setting-up-index-as-the-default-route-for-a-controller#answer-5254626))

Answer (score 3):

I just want add to Embram's answer that the best practice is to add routes from most detailed to general:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Route1",
                url: "Mail/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Mail", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Route2",
                url: "{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're confused on *where* the routes are defined in an MVC 4 application.

You're `global.asax` should look like (by default):

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
    }
}
```

Where `RouteConfig` is defined in `/App_Start/RouteConfig.cs` as looks like (by default):

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Knowing this, you should be able to edit the routes as needed.

Comment: Thanks, that make more sense. The MSDN tutorial I was was reading may be a bit out of date.... http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-custom-routes-cs