# MVC3 routing: {controller}/{action} + {controller}/{id}

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

`{controller}/{action} + {controller}/{id}`:

How can I make the routing pattern distinguish between the 2?

The first one should link to **Home/Dealers** (Home-controller, Dealer-action)

The second should link to **Store/Audio** (Store-controller, Audio = parameter)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at routeconstraints. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx#adding_constraints_to_routes

Answer (score 0):

Create custome route

Global.asax

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Store",
    "Store/{parameter}/",
    new { controller = "Store", action = "Index", parameter = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

StoreController.cs

```
public class StoreController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string parameter)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, i have it working now with store/{parameter} and {controller}/{action}. i had the order of the routes initially wrong.

Comment: Exactly. Make sure the default route is the **last** route! As mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/973212/277649