# ASP.NET MVC project FTP to IIS server

Tags: iis, model-view-controller, ftp

I have an MVC project that I am trying to deploy to a hosting service that uses an IIS server. I have already FTP'd the files to the root directory, checked that my permissions are correct, and made sure the server is working. My problem is that it appears that the server is looking for a default.html page in my root directory, which does not exist, nor do I want it to exist. When i currently navigate to my website it says "You do not have permission to view this directory or page." The project runs perfectly in my local host. How do I get it to run on the server without creating a new index/default page?

Here is my RouteConfig file

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
          name: "EmailPDF",
          url: "emailpdf",
          defaults: new { controller = "Emails", action = "SendPDFEmail",  }
          );

      routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973205/asp-net-mvc-default-route

Comment: @LexLi my map routing already looks like that. edited my post to show

Comment: Really? "already looks like that"? Read carefully the routes in those answers and do your experiments.

Comment: I added the role: "anonymous" to the default maproute and it did not change anything. If I copy the exact code from that post, i get an error, cannot convert from type <anynomous string controller string action string role> to string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set "Homepage" in Asp.Net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142003/set-homepage-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Another existing thread, though the key points were already there in the first link.